# peg.jsにて区切り文字とした'<' ,'>'をParserの状況によって意味を変えられるようにしたい

Tags: javascript

peg.jsにおいて
以下のようなparserを書きました

**perser.pegjs**

```
Start
= c:(Content+) EOL {
  return c;
}

Content 
= openId:OpenTag c:(Content)+ closeId:CloseTag {
    if (openId !== closeId) {
        throw new Error( "expect </ " + openId+ "> but </" + closeId + ">");
    }
    return { type:'element', id:openId, content:c};
}
/txt:ContentText {
  return {type:'txt', content:txt.trim()}
}


ContentText = [^<>\n]+ { return text();}

OpenTag = "<" id:[0-9]+ ">" { return parseInt(id.join(''))}
CloseTag = "</" id:[0-9]+ ">" { return parseInt(id.join(''))}


EOL = [\n]*
```

以下の入力を受け取りjsonを吐きます

```
<1>abc</1><2>def<3>ghi</3></2>
```

**出力**

```
[
   {
      "type": "element",
      "id": 1,
      "content": [
         {
            "type": "txt",
            "content": "abc"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "type": "element",
      "id": 2,
      "content": [
         {
            "type": "txt",
            "content": "def"
         },
         {
            "type": "element",
            "id": 3,
            "content": [
               {
                  "type": "txt",
                  "content": "ghi"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

このparserではContentText に **<,>** を含めることが出来ませんが
なんとか含ませたい場合どの様にparserをかけばよろしいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

(質問者様による自己回答を Wiki として投稿しています)

一応自己解決しましたのでいかに修正内容を纏めます。
もっとスマートな方法があればご教授下さい。

```
Start = c:(Content+) EOL {
    return c;
}

Content = open:OpenTag c:Content+ close:CloseTag {
   return { type:'element', id:open, content:c};
}
/
txt:Text {
  return {type:'txt', content:txt.trim()}
}

Text = txt:(NotOpenTag/NotCloseTag/NotTagNotEOL)+ { return txt.join('').trim(); }

NotTagNotEOL = [^<>\n]   { return text();}

NotOpenTag = "<" !Digit !"/" { return text();}
/!Digit ">" { return text();}

NotCloseTag = "</" !Digit { return text(); }

OpenTag = "<" id:Digit ">" { return id;}
CloseTag = "</" id:Digit ">" { return id; }

Digit = [0-9]+  { return parseInt(text()); }

EOL = [\n]*
```